# Overwrite Access Database resulting Unrecognized Format

Tags: c#, winforms, web

I already can overwrite the access database into another folder in my computer. But, when I open the access database that already successfully overwrite, my database is 0 byte and it says it unrecognized format.

I made an simple application and website, but the database is on the application, however I want to access that database also from the website, so I think about copy the database file. However, once the database already overwrite (there is no error happening), it is says unrecognized format once I open the file.

How can I fix this?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
private string dirA = @"D:\Destination A\Database\db1.accdb";
private string dirB = @"D:\Destination B\App_Data\db1.accdb";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!File.Exists(dirB))
                {
                    File.Copy(dirA, dirB);
                }

                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(dirB, string.Empty);
                }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Did you notice the fact that if the destination file exists you overwrite it with an empty string (zero bytes length)?

Comment: As @Steve points out, if the file dirB exists, you effectively destroy it by writing an empty string (0 bytes) over it.  Hence, when you try to open it, you get the "unrecognized format" error because the bytes of the file (there are none) don't match what database engine is expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always overwrite the destination database then you need to check if it exists and in positive case Delete it before executing the copy

```
private string dirA = @"D:\Destination A\Database\db1.accdb";
private string dirB = @"D:\Destination B\App_Data\db1.accdb";
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(dirB))
    {
       File.Delete(dirB);
    }
    File.Copy(dirA, dirB);
}
```

Your actual code writes an empty string if the destination file exists. The File.WriteAllText overwrite the file and so, it is no more a valid Access database